# drawInRect method works too slow

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect

Now i have following:

```
- (void)drawRect
{
    // some drawing

    [bgImage drawinRect:self.bounds];

    // some drawing
}
```

I have more than 40 views with text and some marks inside. I need to repaint all these views on user tapping - it should be really fast!

I instrumented my code and saw: 75% of all execution time is `[MyView drawRect:]` and 95% of my drawRect time is `[bgImage drawinRect:self.bounds]` call. I need to draw background within GPU nor CPU. How is it possible?

What i have tried:

1. Using subviews instead of drawRect. In my case it is very slow because of *unkickable* color blending.
2. Adding UIImageView as background don't helps, we can't draw on subviews ...
3. Adding image layer to CALayer? Is it possible?

**UPDATE:**

Now i am trying to use CALayer instead of drawInRect.

```
- (void)drawRect
{
    // some drawing

    CALayer * layer = [CALayer layer];
    layer.frame = self.bounds;
    layer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
    layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    layer.contentsCenter = CGRectMake(capInsects.left / image.size.width,
                                      capInsects.top / image.size.height,
                                      (image.size.width - capInsects.left - capInsects.right) / image.size.width,
                                      (image.size.height - capInsects.top - capInsects.bottom) / image.size.height);

    // some drawing
}
```

Nothing instead of this new layer is visible right now. All my painting is under this layer i think...

Comment: Using subviews or image views makes a lot of sense. Can you expand on what you mean by "unkickable color blending"? What effect are you trying to get?

Comment: I draw 40 view with 2 labels inside each. I need to draw new set and animate from old to created. Animation was terrible laggy because of color blending of 80 UILabels. Now animation is very smooth by i have latency after tapping.

Comment: Can you post a picture with before & after to help us get an idea of what you mean? How are you running the animation?

Comment: I am developing custom calendar app. I need to draw buttons manually to avoid labels color blending.

Answer (score 1):

I would use UILabels; you can reduce the cost of blending by giving the labels a background color or setting `shouldRasterize = YES` on the layer of the view holding those labels. (You'll probably also want to set `rasterizationScale` to be the same as `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`).

Another suggestion:

There are lots of open-source calendar components that have probably had to try and solve the same issues. Perhaps you could look and see how they solved them.

Comment: I've tried shouldRasterize on UIButton, but this doesn't help. Animation still lagging.

Comment: I've checked right now. This thick works but it gives half boost of manual drawing in drawRect.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're saying. If it's still too slow, you might try pre-computing images for the text, since rendering an image will almost certainly be faster than rendering text directly.

Comment: Text rendering is not my problem. Instruments app told me that 95% of my drawing is background drawInRect. I'm trying to use GPU inseat of CPU for background drawing

Comment: To use the gpu, just put your background in an image view.

Comment: If this UIImageView will be subview of my view - i cant draw on it like on background. If this UIImageView will be behind my view - i got color blending ... because my view should be semi-transpanent

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "I can't draw on it like on background"; perhaps you could post a sample that shows the poor performance?

Comment: With "I can't draw on it like on background" i mean my painting in drawRect is behind subviews...

Comment: I've just added another idea to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this, but i am working on my own components and it have much more base functionality. Sometimes I'll create own framework based on this component. I found 2 opensource ios calendars: "iOS kal" and "Tapku library" - they all use drawing of all tiles in single drawRect.